# Save and Load the state of Data tables (i.e ColReorder, ColVis plug-ins) to/from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Is possible to save and load the states of Data tables (i.e ColReorder, ColVis plug-ins) to/from database? I had tried with these, but i am not getting still.
Below is my code to load the states from db. I am getting the response as json object while loading the page. But its not taking changes as specified states from my db.

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings, oData) {
        var o;
        $.ajax({
            "url": "getStatus.do",
            "async": false,
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function (json) {
                o = json;
            }
        });
        return o;
    },
});
```

Please help me out if any one has implemented the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Data Manager (CRUD) Add-on plugin with Datatable. [Here](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html)
is the link for it.